# Private MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

Does MySql support private stored procedure? If not what would you sagest to do with helping procedures that only used inside other "main" procedures?

Comment: what do you mean by that? when did mysql started supporting moduler/oop programing? if can tell what you are trying to acheive then we may help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using hash (`#`) prefix for such procedures.
For ex:

```
#myfunc()
```

Comment: you can't use such prefix. which version are you talking about?